# Authenticated users missing from users_roles table

Tags: users, database

I have created several authenticated users in my site through the `admin/people/create` interface. However, these users are not showing up in the `users_roles` table. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong.

When creating these users I used fake emails, so authentication emails where not received. However, I've turned off the "require email authentication option." Also, when using dpm() on a variable the contains all the users created from a `user_load_multiple` I can see that they have a `2` in the user role. So why is it not in the database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not an "issue" - but the authenticated user role is not registered in the `users_role` table.  For this type of user, the status is determined by the field `status`in the `users` table.

AFAIK, *every* user registered in the `users` table is considered having the "authenticated user" role, so there is no need to explicitly register this role in the  `users_role` table. Instead, users having this should have their status set to "blocked" when you want to "strip" them of any grants.

Comment: Perfect, that actually makes the queries I was trying to do easier.